# Best way to manage an S3 Bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, storage, acl

I have been trying for a month and a half now to transfer files and update ACL permissions.

My bucket in question is 28gigs, and has over 45,000 objects in it.

It generally takes three days to do it. I've tried the following :

- Bucket Explorer
- CloudBerry
- s3sync
- s3cmd
- s3 organizer
- s3fox

And quite frankly, none of them can handle it. All of them die after a few hours of running the process of copying these files or updating their ACL's.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for stating the obvious here but why not update them in multiple sessions?

Comment: Just queueing so many transfers while reliant on a network connection and Amazon's S3 API is likely to be problematic. Surely uploading then updating the permissions a couple of gigs at a time would make more sense.

Comment: Right..Not a bad idea. I guess I never assumed it would be this tedious. ;D